# After using a transform to fill up a vector, the new c++11 for loop doesn't work

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, for-loop, vector

I am currently learning STL, and am on a topic of mapping, filtering etc.
I recently learned lots of new stuff such as the new c++11 for loop(with auto)
I (kinda) don't understand the way things work, but i wanted to use the "transform" function to fill up another vector(mapping topic). But after i build the program and run it, it gives me an error which goes as:
"cannot seek value-initialized vector iterator"

I am not sure what that means or what error there is, could you guys help me understand the for loop concept and what im doing wrong here?

p.s the operator of the "transform" in the end was done with a lambda thingy(which i still have to learn and have no idea about) in the tutorial, i tried to make a function and guessed that it would work.

```
int mult(int a) {
    return a * 10;
}
int main() {
    vector<int> v{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    vector<int> v1;
    for (auto& i : v) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    if (v1.empty()) cout << "v1 is empty" << endl;
    cout << "v1" << endl;
    transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v1.begin(), mult);
    for (auto &i : v1) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`transform` doesn't extend a range, it only writes to on an existing one that's assumed non-empty. `v1` is empty, so it cannot be made to store the result of the transformation. Your options are to either make sure `v1` holds enough elements for the algorithm to overwrite:

```
vector<int> v1(v.size());
```

or to use [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to create an iterator which increases the size of `v1`:

```
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(v1), mult);
```

Comment: Ah i see now what this is all about. Haven't learned this back_inserter thing yet. Which library is it in? Thanks for the answer. I didn't think that there needed to be space in the vector, thought it would just insert stuff.

Comment: @DavidPetriashvili it's in `<iterator>`

Comment: @DavidPetriashvili In general it's not possible for an iterator to insert or delete from the container it's iterating over. Only specialized iterators like that returned from `back_inserter` can do that.

Comment: @john Yes i see, i actually tried doing front_inserter but the code went balls. What is wrong with doing the same thing but from front? (added the <iterator> lib)

Comment: @DavidPetriashvili - Consult the documentation of the iterator and containers you use. `std::vector` doesn't support insertion at the front, for that you'd need `std::deque`

Comment: I haven't even been told to read any documentation ever. I'll search for it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is UB (undefined behaviour), it does not fill anything:

```
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v1.begin(), mult);
```

you want:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(v1), mult);
```

As a general rule, operations on begin/end iterators do not change the size of the container.

Your code just spewed data into an empty buffer, corrupting memory or worse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a newbie, so i don't know what UB means. Could you tell me?

Comment: UB is *undefined behaviour*. It's bad, your program could do anything.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!